# Query for draft or scheduled post

Tags: get-posts, post-status

What should be the query for checking if there is any draft or scheduled post, I'm not able to make which arguments to take.

Thanks

Comment: You can use these arguments http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Status_Parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$draft = wp_count_posts()->draft ? : 0;
$sheduled = wp_count_posts()->future ? : 0;

echo "There are $draft draft posts and $sheduled scheduled posts";
```

See Codex for [wp_count_posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_count_posts)

Comment: also set permission for wp_count_posts() so that private posts will also be considered.

Comment: Yes @VinodDalvi, if it is the desired behaviour... I link Codex so OP can read and decide how to use. Setting permission will work only if user is currently logged in, so it has no effect for *guests*. Reading the question there is no way to understand what the OP want to do...